# How to get the percentage frequency of letters at each position from a list of strings in python?

Tags: python, list, position, grouping

I have a list of strings like this:

## list:

```
('aatt')
('aaga')
('aaac')
('gtag')

#the real list have thousands of strings
```

the optimal desired result is a tabular separated file like this:

```
0       1       2       3
a:75%   a:75%   a:50%   a:25%
g:25%   t:25%   g:25%   c:25%
                t:25%   g:25%
                        t:25%
```

(the header is not necessary)

I made a bash script to do it, but now I'm learning python and I would like to do with it.

This is my bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(echo 1 2 3 4) 

do echo $i && cat FILE | grep N -v | awk -F "" '{print $'$i'}' | awk -f ./WC 

done
```

where WC is the following wordcounter:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[^a-zA-Z]+"
}
{
     for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
          words[toupper($i)]++
}
END {
    for (i in words)
         print i, words[i]
}
```

Comment: We're not here to produce complete, working programs on demand for you. What have you tried so far? What about it didn't work? And even more importantly, **how does us writing the code for you help you learn Python?**

Comment: If you can handle that problem in _bash_, surely Python will feel too easy :)

Comment: It isn't a very complex problem. I made a scrip using awk and other bash comand. I only want some orientation in python in order to do it.

Comment: @Geparada, start with [`readline`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) wrapped in a `while` loop of some sort. :)

Comment: Why not paste the bash code? That would help remove the ambiguity from this question. Let us know, specifically what parts of the bash script you're having a problem implementing with Python. Otherwise, this question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow and will likely be closed.

Comment: I didn't post my bash code because I wanted to do a simpler question, but I'll take your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting some harsh comments here but I will try to give you some pointers :) From the looks of your data it seems like you are trying to do SNP calling for a list of sequences you have? Given such data:

```
d = ['aatt','aaga','aaac','gtag']
```

The first thing you should do is preallocate a dictionary that would store the letter counts per position. I am assuming here you only have 4 letters i.e. a,t,c and g and you know the maximum length of your strings. If you don't you can extract it as such:

```
maxLen = max(map(len,l))
```

Once you have that, create your dictionary:

```
freqDict = dict([(i,{'a':0.0,'t':0.0,'c':0.0,'g':0.0}) for i in xrange(maxLen)])
```

And then store the letter counts per position:

```
for s in l:
  for i,b in enumerate(s):
    freqDict[i][b] += 1
```

This should result in this:

```
In [26]: freqDict
Out[26]: 
{0: {'a': 3.0, 'c': 0.0, 'g': 1.0, 't': 0.0},
 1: {'a': 3.0, 'c': 0.0, 'g': 0.0, 't': 1.0},
 2: {'a': 2.0, 'c': 0.0, 'g': 1.0, 't': 1.0},
 3: {'a': 1.0, 'c': 1.0, 'g': 1.0, 't': 1.0}}
```

From then on, its up to you how you want to print your results. Might be more efficient to print your results with one position per line so you don't have to iterate over the entire list of positions 4 times i.e.

```
for i in freqDict:
  vs = freqDict[i]
  sumvs = sum(vs.values())
  print '%d\t%s' % (i,'\t'.join(['%s:%.1f' % (b[0],b[1]*100/sumvs) for b in vs.items()]))
```

Generating:

```
0   a:75.0  c:0.0   t:0.0   g:25.0
1   a:75.0  c:0.0   t:25.0  g:0.0
2   a:50.0  c:0.0   t:25.0  g:25.0
3   a:25.0  c:25.0  t:25.0  g:25.0
```

Comment: Thanks four your guidance!
No one force to you to answer my question, however you help me a lot :)

Comment: No worries. It might though still be a good idea (as many people have urged you as well) to paste your awk script and show how your input file looks like. That way people can give you other solutions as well as way in on optimizations since I am guessing you are dealing with very large datasets.

Comment: I imagine something clever could be done with the Numpy module if speed was an issue. Numpy adds an array object and lots of other useful tools for statistical analysis and scientific computing. I would recommend it once you're more familiar with the Python basics.